# Mount 'hibernated' windows partition, ciphered with bitlocker

Tags: linux, mount, windows, ntfs

My windows 8.1, ciphered with bitlocker, was damaged during system update process somehow. Now it boots only to recovery mode and I can't use password for bitlocker drive unlocking. I lost my recovery key for bitlocker.

I managed to unlock it from linux (using dislocker and password). Then I've tried to recover the bitlocker recovery key from hiberfil.sys but Elcomsoft's software which I used says my hibernation file is broken.

I'd like to remove hiberfile (and pagefile) from this unlocked partition. Unfortunately on my Arch Linux (run on root account):

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile dislocker-file /windows/
```

does not work and gives me:

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/mnt/1/dislocker-file': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I don't really care about system damage, because it's already broken but I'd like to try to unlock my windows system so I don't have to do clean reinstall. Any ideas?